# What is the difference between AWS site-to-site VPN and AWS client VPN?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, site-to-site-vpn

I know that **site-to-site** is using IPSec (layer 3), but **client** is using TLS (application layer). It seems like both are actually *site to site* vpns after reading articles/ [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpn-connections.html) online.

I guess the protocol (IPSec vs TLS) is their only difference, which has implications on when you would use which one. I would guess that both are equally good, and you should always use TLS on the application layer anyway, even on top of client VPN.

How do you decide which one to use, and why?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In general the protocol doesn't have much to do with it. You can have **IPSec** tunnels in both *site-to-site* or *client* (aka *road warrior*) configurations, just like you can have [**OpenVPN**](https://openvpn.net/) (TLS) tunnels in both *site-to-site* or *client* setups. It's a matter of configuration and purpose, not the protocol used.

#### Site-to-Site VPN

- typically **1-to-1** configurations
- both sides in general have similar configuration
- both sides have fixed IP address
- either side can initiate or restart the connection
- both typically have a network behind them (e.g. two office networks connected)
- you can run a routing protocol (BGP, OSPF, ...) over the tunnel
- the networks can communicate both ways

#### Client-to-Site VPN

- typically **N-to-1** configurations, with *N* clients connecting to *1* server
- server and client configs are different
- clients don't need fixed IP address
- only clients initiate the connections (because the server doesn't know the client's current IP)
- client is typically just a single laptop with no network behind it
- routing only permits one IP per client, no BGP or OSPF supported
- only client to the site behind the server connectivity is permitted, generally the site can't initiate connection to the client

That's roughly the difference between site to site and client to site VPNs.

In AWS the *VPN Gateway* uses *IPsec protocol* and the *Client VPN* uses *OpenVPN protocol* but that's just how AWS implemented the services. However in general it's perfectly possible to use either protocol in either setup.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: TLS is easier for client VPN setups as it works behind NATs without IPsec VPN  passthrough and you can have many connections from behind the same NAT. Using IPsec for client VPN would cause way more support tickets.

Comment: @EsaJokinen IPSec can be encapsulated in UDP for client access. The standard IPSec NAT-Traversal extension does that, L2TP that uses IPsec internally does that too, some versions of Cisco VPN that use IPSec do that too. The native IPSec ESP protocol is generally only used for site to site tunnels, otherwise it runs inside UDP.

Comment: Surviving multiple NATs might still be tricky, despite the NAT-traversal extension.

Answer (score 3):

> you should always use TLS on the application layer anyway, even on top of client VPN

TLS is a protocol that has many different uses. The most common one is in HTTPS but many other protocols use it too as it's a standard way to encrypt network traffix. That's the application level.

In AWS Client VPN it's being used one level down - to encrypt the actual network layer traffic (level 3), regardless of what's passing through the tunnel. They chose to use TLS because it's a standard well known protocol.

Amazon could have implemented Client VPN with IPsec or even invent their own protocol but they chose TLS because it's a proven technology.

And yes, you can indeed use HTTPS over this VPN which is technically TLS over TLS but with different endpoints and certificates.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that site-to-site is using IPSec (layer 3),

This does appear to be the case.

> but client is using TLS (application layer).

Not sure where you are reading that? the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-user/user-getting-started.html) seems to indicate that AWS client VPN is openvpn based

OpenVPN uses TLS for negotiation, but does not use it for the actual data.

> It seems like both are actually site to site vpns after reading articles/ docs online.

Openvpn is capable of performing both client and site to site VPN tasks, but AWS seems to be using it as a client VPN, I don't see anything in the documentation that would allow you to say allocate a whole netblock to an individual VPN client.

Of course you could run a NAT on the VPN client, to allow all the devices behind it to use the VPN, but that would not be using the service as-intended.

> I guess the protocol (IPSec vs TLS) is their only difference

Site to site and client VPNs have different priorities, which drives different typical protocol choices.

The problem with ipsec is it was designed in an era before pervasive NAT. The result is it runs directly on top of IP and does not have anything analagous to TCP/UDP port numbers that NATs can use to disambiguate multiple client sessions.

So using an IPsec VPN from behind a NAT is a dicey proposition. It may not work at all, or more insidiously it may work, but only for one client at a time.

For a site to site VPN this is not usually a big deal, your edge device will most likely have a public IPv4 from a consistent ISP.

For a client on the go, it's a big issue. So using a VPN soloution that runs on top of UDP or even TCP (openvpn can do either, I'm not sure which configuration amazon use) is likely a good idea. Even if it is less efficient.